Robot.createScreenCapture always captures non-convolved image
I'm currently writing a code that does simple image processing. In my code, pressing various buttons on the screen does convolution and/or manipulates each pixel's rgb values to show different effects, such as grayscaling and edge detecting.
I've added a magnifying glass function, to zoom into certain parts of the processed image and paint them into a separate panel. To capture whatever is on the processed image, I've used the createScreenCapture method in the Robot class to capture the area around my mouse cursor. Problem is, the magnified image always shows the unprocessed, original image instead of the processed one.
Below is the code that draws in the Images into the screen. I used ImageIcon to force the image to fit into the panels in the frame.
public void showOnScreen(){
        ImageIcon originalIcon = new ImageIcon(original_img_panel.loadedImg);
        img = originalIcon.getImage();
        newimg = img.getScaledInstance(550,550,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        originalIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        original_img_panel.original_label.setIcon(originalIcon);

        //processed image goes through the same process
}

And below is the code that does the screen cap. It captures a small rectangular region around the mouse cursor and saves it into zoomPanel.zoomedInImage, then draws that with current_zoom_perc set by the user, into zoomPanel.
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Point mousePoint = e.getPoint();
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        zoomPanel.zoomedInImage = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(mousePoint.x, mousePoint.y, 150, 150));
        zoomPanel.zoomedInImage = zoomPanel.zoomedInImage.getScaledInstance((int)(150*current_zoom) ,(int)(150*current_zoom_perc),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        zoomPanel.repaint();
    } 
    catch (AWTException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

Example of an image that got processed with edge detection, and then magnified (shown in the bottom right corner). The magnified image is the magnified version of the original image.
I'm not really sure what can I change here.. Thank you!
EDIT: Here is class zoomedInPanel, the class for object zoomPanel.
public class zoomedInPanel extends JPanel {
    JLabel zoomedInLabel = new JLabel();
    Image zoomedInImage;
    boolean cursorInPanel = false;
    public zoomedInPanel() {
        setBounds(950,555,150,150);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        zoomedInLabel.setBounds(0,0,150,150);
        zoomedInLabel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(zoomedInLabel);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(zoomedInImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}


changing the image variable doesn't change the Icon of the label. You need code like: label.setIcon( new ImageIcon( zoomedInImage);

Class for object zoomPanel overrides paintComponent() to draw the zoomed-in image in it, it does not make use of ImageIcon. I've added an edit to the post with the class zoomedInImage for reference.


Class names should start with an upper case character. 2) You should not be updating variables in the zoom panel class directly. If you want to change the image them you should have a method like setZoomImage(...). That method would then invoke repaint().  3) Not really understanding your code. In the zoom panel you try to paint an image as a background. But then you have a JLabel with a white background that will paint on top of the image. 4) How do you know the mouseMoved code is executed? I don't see where you add the MouseMotionListener to the panel.



don't like that you are using a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 6) Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

